# Почему в данном примере возвращает null?

Tags: javascript, null

Почему в данном примере выражение возвращает `null`?

```
const a = 0 || true && null;
console.log(a); //null
```

Comment: @yar85 у `&&` [приоритет](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) выше (6) чем у `|| ` (5)

Comment: @Greg--, :) а я всегда считал одинаковым. Спасибо.

Comment: В это задаче получается из-за приоритетов сначала идет проверка левой части выражения `true && null` ПРОВЕРКА: true может быть преобразован в false? - нет, значит возвращаем правую часть, а так как левая часть `0 || ...` т.е. 0 преобразовывается в false, по этому в результате получаем `null`

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) по человски написано

Comment: Интересно кто поставил ДУБЛИКАТ хотя там сравнивают функции (соответсвенно сначала все функции по очереди вызываются) а тут сравнивают значения?

Comment: @Greg--, замени функции на значения и получишь свой пример ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: _«ПРОВЕРКА: true может быть преобразован в false?»_ - совсем не так. Вычисляется булевое значение операнда, которое затем соотносится с константным `false`. Возможность преобразования при этом не проверяется, т.е. типкаст значения левого операнда (когда таковое присутствует) безусловный, выполняется в любом случае кроме прерывания ошибкой на получении его значения.

Comment: Ты ошибаешься в своих предположениях о порядке проверки. Подробнее смотри в дубликате.

Comment: @yar85, что-то я вообще не понял твой комментарий :)

Comment: @Greg--, под приоритетом лучше понимать расстановку скобок, а не порядок выполнения, например в твоем случае высший приоритет, значит всего лишь `0 || (true && null)` а не `(0 || true) && null` - как было бы в случае одинакового приоритета. При этом сами значения продолжают вычисляться слева направо

Comment: @Grundy, бывает.

Comment: @Greg--, проверить это можно достаточно просто, заменив 0 на 1 и увидев, что результат станет 1, а все, что было после `||` даже не будет вычислено.

Comment: Благодарю всех!)

Comment: @Grundy Понял, не прав я

Comment: @yar85 про проверку возможности преобразования написано [в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: @Grundy Меня сбили как раз пример со скобками по ссылке на дубликат, так как в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) написано что скобки как раз меняют последовательность выполнений операций. Пойду еще почитаю 0.0

Comment: @Greg--, похоже что в документации допущена неточность... более точно было бы написать _"... если значение `expr1` ложное (falsy)"_. Или, другими словами: _"... если преобразованное к булевому типу значение `expr1` является `false`"_. Предлагаю свериться [со спецификацией](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Comment: @Greg--, не, скобки **могут** менять последовательность, и первый пример в документации как раз и показывает, что скобки могут ничего не менять. В дубликате скобки добавлены как раз для того, чтобы не было споров о приоритетах и всем остальном